# Pandas dataframe sentiment analysis always same value printed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hope you can help

I have the below - I'm trying to determine sentiment for a few values in a csv.

That seems to work OK one at a time, but when I try to add a new column to my pandas dataframe to store it, all the values are the same.

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

```
In [22]:        import pandas as pd
    ...:        from textblob import TextBlob
    ...: 
    ...:        path = 'Desktop/sentiment.csv'
    ...:        df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')          
    ...: 
    ...:        for row in df.iterrows():
    ...:            blob = TextBlob(str(df.Text))
    ...:            df['sentiment'] = blob.sentiment.polarity
    ...:     

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
                                              Text  sentiment
0              I love this game, I think its great   0.107143
1  really buggy, not a good experience, do not buy   0.107143
2                        not too bad, not too good   0.107143

In [24]:
```

Comment: godfryd has posted an answer below that should resolve your issue. What's happening is that in your loop, you're setting the *entire* `'sentiment'` column to the same value for each evaluation of the loop body. So what winds up happening is that the whole column takes on whatever value its given on the last execution of the loop. In this case, it's the *whole series*, `df['Text']`, turned into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `iterrows` try this:

```
df['sentiment'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x)).sentiment.polarity)
```

Comment: Ahh that's brilliant thank you. My understanding is, that the 'Text' value, is assigned to X & then that X value is passed to the text blob, is that correct?

Comment: @kikee1222 the Text value for each row is assigned to x and the result of this apply is a whole pandas Series with the results of the function executions for individual rows. You can read more about apply in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html